# cannot get any value from BehaviorSubject in observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to pass some data inside observable function from several service to a non related component without using service call by using BehaviorSubject. However, not all of them work.

service.ts

```
export class Data{
 name:string;
 age:number;
 class:string;
 constructor(){
  this.name = "";
  this.age = null;
  this.class="";
 }
}
@Injectable()
export class InfoService {

 public myData = new Data();
 dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.myData);
 dataInfo = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

 constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
 getData(id:Id):Observable<any>{
  this.http.get(url+"id="+id).pipe(first()).subscribe(res=>{
    this.myData = res['data'];
    this.dataSubject.next(this.myData);
    console.log(this.myData);
  }
  return this.http.get(url+"id="+id);
}
```

I got the value from the console.log in the service file.

componenet.ts

```
export class Employee implements OnInit{

    constructor(public infoS:InfoService ){}

    ngOnInIt(){
        this.infoS.dataInfo.subscribe(res=>{
          console.log(res);
        }
    }
}
```

in the component file, the console.log give me an empty Data object. And I check the inspect console, The component line run before the service line run. Is there any way I can set the component run after the service run? 
In addition, as I mentioned it in the beginning, some of them are working. And the console shows that the working one has the component line run before and after the service line. So the working one, the component line actually run twice, one is before the service line, and one after that makes it work.

Comment: Which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: where will you call your `getData()` method of service in component?

Comment: why dont you subscribe to behavior subject directly? currently you have subscribed to dataInfo instead of dataSubject

Comment: I am using angular 8. And the getData() is at a different component with the service component. There is no relation between

Answer (score 1):

`dataInfo` will get value of behavior subject for only first time, and will not be updated whenever behavior subject is updated, so you need to subscribe to `dataSubject` behavior subject directly:

```
ngOnInIt(){
   this.infoS.dataSubject.subscribe(res=>{
          console.log(res);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is still not working for me. I got the default Data value when directly subscribe the behavior subject

Comment: That's because maybe you are never calling `getData()` method, so the value is never updated

Comment: I am confuse. The getData() method called every time when the info page is load. So I just have to call the getData () service to make it work. Or is there other way to do it.

Comment: you can call getData() in constructor of that service if you want to do it on every page load

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
this.infoS.dataInfo.subscribe(res=>{
   if(res) {
       console.log(res);
   }
}
```